# How can I add an editor without IEditorInput into a RCP application?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'd like to add an editor to an RCP application. I need to leverage the advanced features of editor, such as keywords highlighting.
But it seems that editor have to be associated with an IEditorInput, but I just do not need to persistence the text, store it in memory is OK for me.
Is there any way to do that ? Thanks

-- 
Best Regards

Jeff Zhang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this: http://blog.eclipse-tips.com/2008/06/opening-editor-without-ifile.html

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you create an implementation of IEditorInput that doesn't persist the text?